# Concentration around the median implies concentration around the mean - Theorem 5.1.4 from High-Dimensional Probability

Tags: probability-theory, spheres, means, concentration-of-measure

Let $M$ denote the median of a function $f(X)$ that is Lipschitz continuous with $\left \| f \right \|_{Lip}=1$. I am trying to show that if $\left \| f(X)-M \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq C$, then $\left \| f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq C$, where $\psi_{2}$ is the sub-gaussian norm. I understand that the inverse is true due to the fact that the median minimizes the $L_{1}$ norm which is bounded by the sub-gaussian norm.

For this direction I thought about using

\begin{align}
\left \| f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}=\left \| f(X)-M+M-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\\
\leq\left \| f(X)-M \right \|_{\psi_{2}}+\left \| M-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\\
\leq C+\left \| M-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}
\end{align}

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: did you read the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609200/concentration-around-mean-from-concentration-around-median?rq=1) ?