# Concentration of sum of median-centred independent variables, $\sum_i (X_i - m_{X_i})$

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure

Sub-Gaussian style concentration inequalities exist for the median, i.e. if $X$ is a random variable, then there exist positive constants $c_1, c_2$ such that
$$ \Pr( |X - m_X | \ge t) \le c_1 e^{-c_2 t^2}. $$

My question is if $X_i$ are independent r.v.s indexed by $i = 1 \dots d$ each obeying the above inequality, then are there corresponding bounds like
$$ \Pr( |\sum_i (X_i - m_{X_i}) | \ge t) \le c_3 e^{-c_4 t^2} $$
where $c_3, c_4$ are constants?

---

I know that bounds exist for $\sum X_i - \operatorname{median}(\sum_i X_i)$, and for sub-Gaussian variables in $\sum_i (X_i - E X_i)$ for independent r.v.s $X_i$.

It also seems that using Talagrand's convex inequality we can get bounds where $c_3 \propto 2^d$, (using the lower bound $\Pr( \sum_i (X_i - m_{X_i}) < 0) \ge \Pr(\forall i, X_i - m_{X_i} < 0) \ge 2^{-d} $) but this seems extremely weak and I wonder if it is possible to get something closer to a linear (in $d$) relationship between the constants $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3, c_4$.

It seems that this should be the case because concentration around the mean implies concentration around the median, but the fact that the median is non-linear seems to break the argument from e.g. [Mean concentration implies median concentration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144688/mean-concentration-implies-median-concentration). I would also be very interested if this is possible under some additional constraints, e.g. boundedness.

The context for this problem is trying to prove a result where the sum of the individual medians is tractable, but the median of the sum is not.